# CSS - Max Width and Ellipses

Tags: html, css

I have a span that will contain text.  I would like the span to expand to a maximum of 500px to accommodate the text inside.  After the max is reached I would like the text to display ellipses for any text overflowing the max-width.  Is this possible?  I tried the following, but this did not do the trick.

Thanks

```
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: 44px;
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Which browser did you try? Firefox e.g. does not support the `text-overflow: ellipsis;`-setting.

Comment: This article might help you, well at least in getting it simulated in FF:
http://www.jide.fr/english/emulate-text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-with-css

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
display: inline-block; // This is what you're missing
max-width: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

```css
.elipsis {
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="elipsis" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Spans are display:inline by default, which can cause odd behavior when dimensions are assigned to it. If it's being positioned absolutely anyway, you should use a div or set the span to display:block instead.

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but it's a start :)

---

[This is an interesting article](http://mattsnider.com/css/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/) about getting ellipsis to work on all modern browsers without using javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I found this question via Google and setting `display: block` on my `<a>` tag with ellipsis was the issue

Comment: `display:block` wasn't fine for what I wanted to do, but `display:inline-block` did it perfectly. I was also wanting to have length-limited `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript will truncate your text and add an ellipsis. (Without breaking it in the middle of a word or markup)

[Barelyfitz Truncate js](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/truncate/).

Not sure on the browser compatibility of i, but it should work :)

Hope it helps.