# Problems with LONG NAMES (PHP): how to place 3 DOTS (…) at the end of a fixed SPACE LENGTH

Tags: php, string, long-integer, trim

We are having difficulties displaying `LONG NAMES` on our website and would need help urgently.

We actually need to place IMAGE NAMES under IMAGES that have a `FIXED WIDTH`.  Because image names are sometimes longer than the image width, we don’t want to display the complete name on too many lines because it would not look nice.

We then either want to display the names on 1 (or 2) line(s) maximum (depending on the page).

When the NAME IS LONGER than 1 (or 2) line(s), we would like to CUT THE IMAGE NAME and place 3 DOTS (…) at the end of the line so that the third dot would reach the end of the image.

We have tried to find a solution, but defining a string length is not one of them, because if we define a limit of for example 10 characters then put the 3 dots afterwards, it will not solve the problem since all characters don’t have the same length:

Example 1: AAAAAAAAAA

Example 2: IIIIIIIIII

This solution is inappropriate since the 3 dots will never be placed at the same place (at the end of the image)

Does anyone have a solution?

We would really appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It almost impossible to accomplish a reliable PHP solution for this. PHP has no way to know how the browser will render the texts. Why don't you just use CSS?

Comment: Look at relative [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966326/css-max-width-and-ellipses)

Comment: The 3 dots should be correctly rendered as an elipsis using &hellip;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the physical length of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572602/how-do-i-find-the-physical-length-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

PHP, being a server-side language, has no way to know how the browser will render the text. A CSS solution is way more feasible:

```
div.picture-name{
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/X4N44/).

P.S. Can't guarantee IE support for `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Álvaro, I will talk to the developer about your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the best option but you can place each character within a div or span then you will probably have a control over length of the sting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yagnesh.  We will inquire about your suggestion.